# Creating IBOutlet in Swift results in 'class is not constructible with ()'

Tags: swift

My code compiled fine before upgrading to beta 4, however I think they changed something with IBOutlets.

The old syntax was:

```
@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView
```

The new syntax is:

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
```

This is default code generated by Xcode when I ctrl drag from my xib file to the class file.

However, with this new syntax, I'm unable to construct an instance of my class. Take the following example:

```
class TestViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
}
```

Then if I try to do either

```
var controller = TestViewController(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
```

or

```
var controller = TestViewController()
```

I get an error:

> TestViewController is not constructible with ()

What's the right way to create an instance of my controller then? The only way that currently works for me is to make the outlets optional, but I'd rather not do that.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this.

```
@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView?
```

I know this is not the answer but the error is gone after this.

Answer (score 0):

The solution seems to be to implement the init method in that view controller:

```
init()
{
    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
}
```

I'm not sure why that is.

Comment: when I do this I get a runtime error: "fatal error: use of unimplemented initializer 'init(coder:)' for class"